# Thunderbird can't connect to my mail server

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, ubuntu-16.04

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server and I have to create mail server on it. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.upcloud.com/support/secure-postfix-using-lets-encrypt/) that uses postfix & dovecot. Now I am able to sent email from server using `mail` command to my personal email but Thunderbird fails to connect and configure my created email. Email related processes seems working:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

It could be because of my DNS entries. I'm not expert at these concepts. If you can help me, I'll appreciate it a lot.

P.S. `ufw` is disabled

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your mail server should listen on port 587 (submission) for user agents.  This port should require STARTTLS and Authentication before accepting a message for delivery.  Thunderbird works well with this setup.

Thunderbird will try a few subdomains when it auto-configures.  For the domain `example.com`, configure DNS for `mail.example.com` for the server running postfix and dovecot.  (Replace `example.com` as required for your domain.)  This should be an A record.  Other names can be used such as `imap.example.com`, `smtp.example.com` and `pop.example.com`, but `mail.example.com` works for most protocols.

Comment: dovecot is configured to use port 143 for `imap-login` and 110 for `pop3-login`. Should I change 143 to 587? The tutorial I used was using `let's encrypt` so I think STARTSSL is ok

Comment: no 143 is imap you want to auth via smtp over ssl which is port 587

Answer (score 1):

turns out I didn't uncomment smtp in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ISPs block outbound port 25 to stop people from spamming on their network. They only allow it to their own servers.

You'd have to run postfix on a ssl enabled port and connect to that to send outgoing email